# conditional distribution of $X$ given $\min(X,\alpha)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$ So I want to find a conditional distribution for $X$ given $Y=\min(X,\alpha).$ 
I know that for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
$$P_Y(B)=\int_B 1_{]-\infty, \alpha]}(x)dP_X+P(X>\alpha)\delta_{\alpha}(B).$$

I don't know this will help us to find out the conditional distribution. 
Thank you for any idea.

Comment: It seems that any $$(A,y)\mapsto 1_{y\neq \alpha} \delta_{y}(A) + 1_{y=\alpha}P_{X|Y=y}(A)$$ where $P_{X|Y=\alpha}$ is an arbitrary probability measure is a regular conditional probability of $X|\min(X,\alpha)$.

Comment: if we take a non negative function $h$ from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ a way to find the conditional distribution is to write :$$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}h(x,y)dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(x,y)dP_{X|Y=y}(x))dP_Y(y)$$

Comment: And we have $$\int h(X,\min(\alpha,X))dP=\int_{]-\infty,\alpha]}h(x,x)dP_X(x)+\int_{]\alpha,+\infty[}h(x,\alpha)dP_X(x)$$ I wonder how to find $P_{X|Y=y}$ from this equality

Comment: So that $$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), P_{X|Y=y}(B)=1_{]-\infty,\alpha]}(y)\delta_y(B)+1_{]\alpha,\infty[}(y)\frac{P_X(B \cap ]\alpha,+\infty[)}{P_X(]\alpha,+\infty[)}$$ supposing that $P_X(]\alpha,+\infty[)>0$